# how can i call multiple ajax request after one request complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

created two functions i want to call the get_name_from_id when my first ajax function get successful but it is not working when i add alert in get_name_from_id function after jsonstring like alert("xyz") it shows but ajax part not exectue

```
   function get_name_from_id(){
    var team_name = ("sahil","krishna");
   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(team_name);
    $.ajax({
    dataType:"json",
    type:"POST",
    url:"fetchidwithname.php",
    data: {team_name : jsonString},
    cache: false,
    success:function(a)
    {
        alert(a);

       }        
    });
   }

$("#matchbet").click(function(){
var matchlist = $("#match_list option:selected").val();
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(matchlist);
$.ajax({
    dataType:"json",
    type:"POST",
    url:"selectedmatch.php",
    data: {matchlist : jsonString},
    cache: false,
    success:function(currentmatch)
    {

    var current_bettable  =  team1 + "_vs_"+ team2 + matchdate;
    var bet_team= '<select id="betting_team"><option value='+ team1 +'>'+ currentmatch.team1 + '</option><option value='+ team2 +'>'+ currentmatch.team2 + '</option></select>';
    $("#teamholder").html(bet_team);
    $("#current_match_table").val(current_bettable);
    get_name_from_id();
        }
    });



});
```

Comment: Remove single quote `'` after first function

Comment: As suggested if `'` remove it from first function, if the issue still persist please check the console and share the error

Comment: Sorry I didnt get where to remove singe quote can you please type here

Comment: Or Can You Please Give a working example for calling multiple ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `complete` method of ajax

Call your function `get_name_from_id()` in `complete` method instead of `success`